# python - strtotime equivalent?

Tags: python

I'm using this to convert date time strings to a unix timestamp:

```
str(int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date,"%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"))))
```

However often the date structure isn't the same so I keep getting the following error message:

> time data did not match format:  data=Tue, 26 May 2009 19:58:20 -0500  fmt=%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z

Does anyone know of any simply function to convert a string representation of a date/time to a unix timestamp in python? I really don't want to have to open a process to call a php script to echo the timestamp everytime time in a loop :)

Comment: Are you saying that the format of your string differs from invocation to invocation? And you want this function to detect the format of your string for you?

Comment: Yeah, that's what he's saying.  The asker is used to PHP's strtotime, which includes such date format autodetection heuristics.

Comment: Why the str(int(...)) around the expression?  Unix timestamps in Python are usually passed around as floating point numbers that allow fractional seconds; you should probably not convert to a string unless you need to print the timestamp directly for some reason.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

parse('Tue, 26 May 2009 19:58:20 -0500').strftime('%s')

# returns '1243364300'
```

Comment: This appears to be a reference to the third-party module here: http://labix.org/python-dateutil.  As far as I know, there is no simple way to parse date strings of unknown format in the Python standard library.

Comment: that answered my issue, it's ok with thirdparty modules for me.

Comment: note: [`.strftime('%s')` for timezone-aware datetime objects can produce invalid results](http://www.enricozini.org/2009/debian/using-python-datetime/)

Comment: @WalterMundt thanks for information otherwise I can't figure out how can it work

Comment: Just a warning to anyone finding this. The `dateutil` module has some bugs and doesn't look like development is very active at the moment