# How to do strtotime function of PHP for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

First: Sorry my bad english ok?
Second: I already looked at this post [python - strtotime equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894010/python-strtotime-equivalent)

So, i'm trying to use the function `strtotime('+{amount} days or minutes')` in Python. This function is PHP, but in Python how to do?

**I'm using Django**

I'm doing this `def`:

```
import time, re

def strtotime(string):
  try:
    now = int(time.time())
    amount = int(re.sub('[^0-9]', '', string))

    if 'minute' in string:
      return now + (amount * 60)
    elif 'hour' in string:
      return now + (amount * 3600)
    elif 'day' in string:
      return now + (amount * 86400)
    elif 'week' in string:
      return now + (amount * 604800)
    elif 'year' in string:
      return now + (amount * (365 * 86400) + 86400)
    else:
      return now + amount
  except:
    return False
```

Comment: What is this function not doing that you wish it were doing? Providing some example input -> expected outputs would be helpful

Comment: Looking through https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-examples, it seems fairly complex and would be challenging to reproduce exactly. Are you only willing to make it work for only some cases?

Comment: I would like to find a way to do it using python's own libraries or improve this function. In Django can you tell me how it works?

Comment: Is this for learning purposes or something important? The simplest answer would be to use dateparser: https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: This is for something important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd recommend looking into simply using `dateparser` as they have implemented similar functionality: https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

---

But, for the sake of completeness, let's also make your function work for your provided use-case. Namely, the `"{num} minute|hour|day|week|year"` example. I assume you'd want to chain these as well, so this works for things like `1 year 3 days 5 minutes`.

```
import time, re


def strtotime(string):
    unit_to_second = dict(
        minute=60, hour=3600, day=86400, week=604800, year=(365 * 86400) + 86400
    )
    accumulator = time.time()

    for match in re.finditer(r"([0-9]) (minute|hour|day|week|year)", string):
        num, unit = match.groups()
        accumulator += float(num) * unit_to_second[unit]

    return accumulator
```

This uses a dict to avoid all the `if`/`elif` branches. It uses a regex with grouping to iterate through all `{num} {timeunit}` patterns of the string, and adds the corresponding length of time to an accumulator which is initialized as the current time, giving us the offset.

Here are examples (formatted to see what it does):

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()))
# ==> 2019-12-10 09:41:16.328347

example = strtotime("1 day")
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(example))
# ==> 2019-12-11 09:41:16.328403

example = strtotime("2 days 5 hours")
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(example))
# ==> 2019-12-12 14:41:16.328686

example = strtotime("1 week 3 days 2 minutes")
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(example))
# ==> 2019-12-20 09:43:16.328705
```